# Setting fillStyle to a list item not working?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm making a drawing program, and it includes a tool that will change the color. It works using two lists, one that has the names of the CSS colors that I chose to represent he colors of the rainbow and black, and the other for the

element that displays which color is selected, then I use a function that increments the value of a variable called selector,  and   and it all works mostly well. The text changes, but the color of the drawing doesn't. I have tried using the array that I'm putting in the fillStyle element in the innerText to see if that array is actually changing, and it is, the fillStyle just isn't changing. Any idea what's wrong? This is my code.

```html
<canvas id='dr' width = '640' height = '480' style = 'display: block;' ></canvas>
<p id = 'color'></p>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('dr');   
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var line = false

function drawType(){
if (line === true){
line = false;}
else{line = true;}
}

 var drawing = false;

function Type(){}
//start the drawing if the mouse is down
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
      drawing = true;
    })
    //stop the drawing if the mouse is up
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
      drawing = false;
    });
    //add an event listener to the canvas for when the user moves the mouse over it and the mouse is down
   var colors = ['DarkRed', 'DarkOrange', 'Gold', 'Green', 'MediumBlue', 'Indigo', 'Violet', 'Black']
var displayColors = ['r', 'Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Indigo', 'Violet', 'Black']
var selector = 0
var color = document.getElementById('color')
var selectedColor = colors[selector]
var selectedColor = colors[selector]
function switchColor(){
if (selector < 8)
{selector = selector + 1; }
else{selector = 1;}
color.innerText = displayColors[selector]
selectedColor = colors[selector]
 ctx.fillstyle = selectedColor;
}
   canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
     
      //if the drawing mode is true (if the mouse button is down)
      if (drawing == true) {
    
    
        //put the rectangle on the canvas at the coordinates of the mouse
        ctx.fillRect(event.pageX, event.pageY, 4, 4)
    }
    }
    );
function clean(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('dr');   
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 640, 480);
}
</script>
<button onclick = 'switchColor()'> Switch drawing color</button>
```

Comment: `ctx.fillStyle`, capital **S**. JS is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('dr');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var line = false

function drawType() {
  if (line === true) {
    line = false;
  } else {
    line = true;
  }
}

var drawing = false;

function Type() {}
//start the drawing if the mouse is down
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  drawing = true;
})
//stop the drawing if the mouse is up
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  drawing = false;
});
//add an event listener to the canvas for when the user moves the mouse over it and the mouse is down
var colors = ['DarkRed', 'DarkOrange', 'Gold', 'Green', 'MediumBlue', 'Indigo', 'Violet', 'Black']
var displayColors = ['r', 'Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Indigo', 'Violet', 'Black']
var selector = 0
var color = document.getElementById('color')
var selectedColor = colors[selector];

function switchColor() {
  if (selector < 8) {
    selector = selector + 1;
  } else {
    selector = 1;
  }
  color.innerText = displayColors[selector];
  selectedColor = colors[selector];
      ctx.fillStyle = colors[selector-1];
}
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {

  //if the drawing mode is true (if the mouse button is down)
  if (drawing == true) {


    //put the rectangle on the canvas at the coordinates of the mouse
    ctx.fillRect(event.pageX, event.pageY, 4, 4)
  }
});

function clean() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('dr');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 640, 480);
}
```

```html
<canvas id='dr' width='640' height='480' style='display: block;'></canvas>
<p id='color'></p>

<button onclick='switchColor()'> Switch drawing color</button>
```

Comment: No they don't have to set it in mousemove and it's even a bad thing to do so, setting the fillStyle is a slow operation, it should be done only when needed.

Comment: fixed it now. I should have checked for spelling before coming up with that 'solution'.